# How to automatically restart a node.js script daily using nodemon?

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I'm using nodemon to manage a node.js process, and I would that process to auto-restart every 24h. Is there an elegant solution for this? I could also just create a cron job that runs every 24h and just do a `kill` but I wanted something nicer :) thanks!

Comment: You can do it by using pm2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nodemon isn't the best tool to manage the node processes in production. It will not restart the app in case of a crash or provide you additional tools and analytics. You can user [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) or [pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2)

```
pm2 start app.js --cron-restart="0 0 * * *"
```

Pm2 will auto restart your app in case of a crash and with `--cron-restart`  it will restart at a given cron time.

Answer (score 0):

And the below script to your `package.json` file

```json
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "start": "node index.js",
  "dev":"nodemon index.js" 
}
```

and run this command:

```bash
npm run dev
```